# PrimeNg Steps components numbering

Tags: primeng

I am trying to implement PrimeNg Steps in my application. Is there any way to delete or replace the numbering?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNg doesn't support that.

But you can hide the numbers with css. Add to your root `css` file the following css:

```
.ui-steps .ui-steps-number {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 40em) {
  .ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-steps-title {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

Working stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-gnwpg1?file=index.html).